# Create string from DiskArbitration CFUUID object

Tags: objective-c, pointers, diskarbitration

In my program I'm using `DiskArbitration` to check some values against a database and, if certain conditions happen, do something before it mounts. I'm using `DARegisterDiskPeekCallback` with this callback:

```
DARegisterDiskPeekCallback(diskSession, kDADiskDescriptionMatchVolumeMountable, 0, determineIfNewDisk, NULL);

void determineIfNewDisk(DADiskRef disk, void* context)
{
    NSDictionary *diskProps = (__bridge NSDictionary *)DADiskCopyDescription(disk);
    CFUUIDCreateString(nil, *(CFUUIDRef *)diskProps[@"DAVolumeUUID"]);
}
```

I'd like to be able to use the UUID and get a string to check in the database, but since `diskProps[@"DAVolumeUUID"]` returns a generic pointer rather than a `CFUUIDRef` pointer, it won't allow me to run `CFUUIDCreateString()`. I attempted to cast the pointer above to a `CFUUIDRef` pointer, but I get this error: `Cast of an Objective-C pointer to 'CFUUIDRef *' ... is disallowed by ARC`. If I don't attempt to cast, `CFUUIDCreateString` will not accept the pointer.

Is there a way to either a) cast the pointer to a `CFUUIDRef` pointer, or b) get the string of the UUID?

Comment: What about `(CFUUIDRef)diskProps[@"DAVolumeUUID"]`?

Comment: Oh, that fixed it! I don't know why I didn't try that. I guess being relatively new to Obj-C doesn't help... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
CFUUIDCreateString(nil, (CFUUIDRef)diskProps[@"DAVolumeUUID"]);
```